# Does cloning a date object in different timezone preserve it's original timezone?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a date object coming from the server in UTC tz.

I want to do some date arithmetics on the client with it like add days etc and sent it back to the server.

Does doing something like:

```
var newDate = new Date(date);          // cloning a date in utc
newDate.setDate(result.getDate() + 7); // expecting the new date to be in utc as well
```

Preserves the original timezone ?

Comment: UTC is not a timezone. It is an offset (of 0), often represented as `Z`.

Comment: @torazaburo - Actually, it's a [system of timekeeping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (as opposed to TAI or UT1), but it's also valid to think of it as an offset *or* as a time zone.  The only quality of a "true" time zone that it does not possess is that it doesn't belong to a specific geographical region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Date objects do not have timezones. Some of their methods, like `getDate` (as opposed to `getUTCDate`) or `toString` use the local timezone to calculate the result they return.

So to answer your question, yes, your sample code preserves the original timezone. Just be sure that, when serializing to send to the server, you use `toISOString()` (or `toJSON()`) instead of `toString()`.

Comment: so theoretically creating two date objects in two different timezones simultaneously will yield the exact same object value ? also, is it safe using js `toJSON()`  to send back  as well ?

Comment: @Michael Re-read this answer. It clearly and correctly states that dates **do not have timezones**. However, they may be expressed in terms of the time given a particular GMT offset, such as +04:00.

Comment: toJSON() is safe since it delegates to toISOString()

Answer (score 2):

The `Date` object internally tracks values only by UTC.  It just keeps a single number, which is the milliseconds elapsed since Midnight on January 1, 1970 UTC.

That said, many of the `Date` object's functions, including the constructor, often work with values that are in the local time zone of the computer where the code is running.  For example, when you do: `new Date(2015,0,1)`, while that would be Midnight on Jan 1st in your time zone, it would equate to a specific UTC-based timestamp (which you can get by calling `.getTime()`).   If you were to do the exact same thing in some other time zone, you would get a different timestamp.  Also, if you were to take your timestamp and load it into the `Date` object in some other time zone, you would get a different local time - which might not even fall on the same day!

You said:

> I have a date object coming from the server in UTC tz.

Since it's not possible for a `Date` object to be transmitted directly, I assume what you actually have transmitted is either a string containing a date and time value that was *parsed* into a `Date` object, or you transmitted a numeric value that is a UTC-based timestamp, which you *loaded* into a `Date` object.

Therefore, asking if the time zone will be preserved from your original input doesn't make sense.  Whatever input you provided when you first created the `Date` object is already lost.  All you have with a `Date` object is that internal number in the UTC time zone, or that number projected to the local time zone.

Comment: great answer, thanks for demystifying js date for me :)

Comment: If you're interested in more, I also have a deep-dive section on Javascript in my Pluralsight course: [Date and Time Fundamentals](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/date-time-fundamentals).